# Accessing a Docker MySQL server from the host machine, without needing the container's IP address

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm writing setup instructions for an application needing a MySQL database, and I'd like it to be easy even for people that don't have a MySQL installation.

Therefore, I'd like to run the MySQL server in a container:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 \
    --name mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db \
    -d mysql
```

And to be able to connect to it this way:

```
mysql -u root -ptest -D my_db
```

Which doesn't work because the MySQL server only listens locally on the container.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So I see three options, none of which fitting my needs:

**1) Using the container IP everytime**

```
mysql -u root -ptest -D my_db -h 172.17.0.4
```

Annoying, the IP will often change and I don't want people to have to update their configuration this much.

**2) Changing the configuration of MySQL inside the container**

Requires to run a `docker exec ...` each time the container is run, so it's annoying as well.

**3) Making a custom image where the configuration suits my needs**

Seems a bit overkill, I'm pretty sure there is a better solution.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `mysql` client is invoked as you did:

```
mysql -u root -ptest -D my_db
```

(i.e. without the hostname) or with `localhost` as hostname it tries to connect to the local server using Unix pipes. A pipe is a special file type and the client communicate with the server through it.

Your MySQL server is not local, it runs on a separate machine. You cannot connect to it using pipes.

As you already noticed, it works if you use the IP address of the container as argument for the `-h` command line option of `mysql`.

You also map the port `3306` of the container to port `3306` of the host machine. This means any TCP connection to port `3306` of the local machine goes through this mapping to the port `3306` of the container, where the MySQL server is listening.

Combining the two above, all you have to do is to put `127.0.0.1` as host name in the `mysql` command line:

```
mysql -u root -ptest -D my_db -h 127.0.0.1
```